# Apache Beam: Accessing WindowParam in a CombineFn

Tags: python, apache-beam

What is the recommended way of accessing window information in a CombineFn?

I have a pipeline setup like this;

```py
            ...
            | "Window into sliding windows"     >> beam.WindowInto(SlidingWindows(7200, 3600))
            | "Combine"                         >> beam.CombineGlobally(BuildState()).without_defaults()
```

I need to use the end of the window inside the CombineFn. Ideally in the `create_accumulator` step. However, I can't seem to access the window information. The following doesn't work. (`AttributeError: '_DoFnParam' object has no attribute 'end' [while running 'Export states/Combine/KeyWithVoid']`)

```py
class BuildState(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        return {
          "datetime": window.end.to_utc_datetime(),
          "values": []
        }
   ...
```

I have tried the following:

- Add the datetime to every element in a ParDo step prior to the CombineFn, but this is too inefficient.
- Have a "Clean up" step after the CombineFn, that fixes the places where I needed to use the datetime in the calculations. This works, but it's a pretty ugly solution.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I was able to work around this by using a GroupBy and ParDo instead:

```py
            ...
            | "Window into sliding windows"     >> beam.WindowInto(SlidingWindows(7200, 3600))
            | "Global grouping"                 >> beam.GroupBy(lambda _: 1)
            | "Combine"                         >> beam.ParDo(ParDoBuildState())
```

```py
class ParDoBuildState(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, group, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        _, events = group

        acc = {
          "datetime": window.end.to_utc_datetime(),
          "values": []
        }

        for event in evens:
           # ... add event to accumulator
```

This works okay, but is a bit slower because it can't distribute the combining.

Comment: I think you can only access the DoFn params in a DoFn but not a CombineFn. I'm wondering if you have to use CombineGlobally, if you can use other types of CombineFn, the window could be reserved and you can access the window param by adding a DoFn step followed by your combine step.

Comment: Are you trying to group all elements that fall into the same window into a single element with the end of window datetime attached? +1 to @YichiZhang 's comment, the window param can only be accessed from DoFn.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to work around this by using a ParDo instead. I updated the post with my solution